# How 2 NetCore projects can interact in different Docker Container

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, containers, microservices

I am trying to build some microservices. Let say I've NetCore Project called "A Project". This project need to consume functions in another NetCore project (let's call it "Base Project"), so I need to add Dependency/Reference to the "Base Project" to makes it work. In my local machine, those 2 projects are in the same solution and it works when debugging.

Now I want put them in docker, and **each project should has their own Container**. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please clarify if you are trying to reference .net core class library to API/Web project ? Or they both are separate API or web projects ? each project having their own container is confusing here. If you are simple referring class library to .net core project (api or web) then it has to be a single container.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response @Imran , Actually I build 1 big system, but as I need to implement microservices, I think it's better to seperate 1 big project to several projects which one of them is "Base Project" that contain common functions. So the other projects can call functions in the Base Project (they don't interact with API, I add **.dll reference**)  

. After that I want to make containers for each project. (**1 container - 1 project**). So in further if something need to be update in common functions, I just need to **only update Base Project Container**. Is this possible?

Comment: What is your base project class library ?  You can reference the base project in any number of projects. but that base project will go with every individual project that is referring it. Say you have project 1 and project 2 referencing base project dll then both these project will include the base project dll in its image . Any time you make any change to your base project you have to rebuild your project 1 and project 2 images. If you want complete independent base project you have to look into http and remote calling.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you @Imran !